# Craft entries won't save (new or edits)

Tags: entry, saveentry

So I am trying to create a new entry, but every time I click save, nothing is actually saved. (see gif)

[image: Saving error]

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED:**

- Overwriting the app folder with a freshly downloaded one (I am already on the latest stable build)
- Increasing `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size` in my php config

**THINGS I HAVE NOTICED**

- It works if I leave the rich text field blank, or with minimal content (like maybe 2 sentences)
- Nothing ever makes it to the database, `_entryversions` remains unchanged
- I don't see anything weird in my log, e.g. no `[error]` tags

Craft Version: 2.6.2990

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have mod_security or Suhosin installed on that box?

Comment: Having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing this issue, what solved it for me was deleting the craft application files and replacing them with the ones from the same release version.

It seems one of them got corrupted at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me here was mod_security. Once that was adjusted w/ the host, all was well again.